# How can you get the String values from an array of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have some code that basically checks the list of queues a current business object has been through. These queues are kept in an array aptly named `_queueNames` of type `IKeyMap`, a custom object my company uses.

I would like to get the textual names of the queues, as I need to check for the presence of a particular keyword and handle it separately if it's hit that particular queue.

I was hoping I could just do something like this;

```
 var queues = _queueNames.ToArray().ToString();
 if (queues.Contains("Condition"))
     DoSomethingElse();
```

but that just gives me the object type, rather than a collection of the values. Looking at the KeyMap object, looks like just a simple key/value pair, might there be another way to do this?

Edit: `KeyMap` class & interface:

```
public interface IKeyMap : IDisposable
{
    string Ley {get;}
    string Field {get;}
}

public class KeyMap : IKeyMap
{
    string _key, field;

    public KeyMap(string key, string field)
    {
        _key = key;
        _field = field;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}_{1}", Key, Field);
    }

    public string Key { get {return _key; } }
    public string Field { get {return _field; } }
}
```

I left out some overrides, such as hashing & the Dispose method since I've got to manually type this out, can't copy-paste from my remote session :(

Comment: Please provide the code for the IKeyMap type. By the way, checking strings is not a good way of going about this. Instead, you should have a Boolean or enum property on your IKeyMap which you should use as a flag to know if it should be handled differently.

Comment: @mason Editted to include most of the KeyMap class

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the objects inside of _queueNames look like, there is no exact answer. One mistake being made here is that you are checking a single string representing an *entire array*. What you want to do is check every *object* in the array for some value, or convert it to a string and check that value.

Here is an example:

```
foreach (var item in array)
{
    if (item.ToString().Contains("Condition"))
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        break;
    }
}
```

Or the LINQ way:

```
if (array.Any(item => item.ToString().Contains("Condition")))
    DoSomethingElse();
```

This specific example only works if the object can be converted into a string that is useful to parse. You could also be accessing a member or invoking a function on said object to get your string. We can't know without more information, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Editted the post to include what the KeyMap type looks like.

Comment: Since your objects implement .ToString() this should work, but doing a .Contains() and hunting for a string is not the optimal way to be checking for some condition as @mason pointed out in his comment on your OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your IKeyMap interface, let's add a Boolean.

```
public string IsSpecial { get; set; }
```

When you create the object, set the IsSpecial flag. Then read it later..

```
var queues = _queueNames.ToArray().ToString();
if (queues.IsSpecial)
    DoSomethingElse();
```

This avoids searching for strings, which is something you want to avoid. What if one of the other queues accidently end up with that string? Or what if you change the special string in one place but forget to change it in another? Or what if the capitalization is different? Or what if the string ends up with a special character that you can't see in it?

And even better way would be with an `enum` instead of Boolean.

```
public HandleType QueueHandleType {get;set;}

public enum HandleType {Normal, Special, SuperSpecial}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is such a monumental application I'm not sure what sort of ramifications that might have and would probably never get approved. I'll try, though!

Answer (score 0):

I might be misreading this, but is there any reason you can't just store the queues by name in array of Key/Value pairs, or even a Dictionary?  For example:

```
var queues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// add your queues to the dictionary, with the key name being your queue name
queues.Add("Queue1", myQueue);
// etc.
```

At that point you have a couple of options.  First, you don't need to loop through the total set of queues you have -- you can simply do this:

```
var specialQueue = queues[mySpecialQueueString];
// do something with it
```

Or you can use LINQ to get any queues whose name contains your special string:

```
var results = queues.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key.Contains(mySpecialString)).ToArray();
```

That said, Mason has a point in that you might need to worry about string matching and the like.  There are, of course, several ways to go about this.  If all queues have a fixed name then I like to make a NameConstants class with a bunch of static strings and refer to members of that class.  Or you can do things like making them all upper and comparing to that.

Comment: Unfortunately, with how big this application is, I don't know how / where else `IKeyMap` is used to go and make changes to it, or to change the type that `_queueNames` is. It sucks to be comparing strings, I certainly agree, but I don't think I have many feasible alternatives.